Loading XML with undefined entity references
This is somewhat of a niche problem, but one I cannot find an answer to. I have some splited XML files with undefined entities that I cannot find a way to access via PHP DOM interface. An example may make things cleaner. Running the following code:
<?php
$xml = "<!DOCTYPE a [<!ENTITY b 'B'>]> <a>&b;</a>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
foreach( $dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node )
    echo $node->nodeType, ",", $node->nodeName, " ";

The result would be 5,b. That is, an DOMEntityReference named b. So far, so good. But if &b; is replaced by, for example, &c;, the code will fail with Entity 'c' not defined and the foreach() will fail, as expected.
By using $dom->recover = true; and libxml_use_internal_errors(true);, it is possible to load the XML, but the undefined entity reference is dropped, even with $dom->substituteEntities = false;.
Perhaps the example above is too complex. Let me simplify it a little. What I'm trying to  find is an way to load an XML like:
<a>&b;</a>

in code above, to show the same result as above. In other words, to be able to load and inspect all entity references of an XML file, these entity references being defined or not.
So, is there some xml_ / libxml_ / DOMDocument option of function, somewhere, anywhere, that stops PHP/libxml from dropping undefined entity references in XML loading?

Why do you need this?

An typical PHP manual is splited in ~11k .XML files, and uses ~13.6K <!ENTITY>s. Yes, thousands. So having a way to analyse and fix up some mishaps via DOM will make the lives few people way less... horrifying.

Your question is not clear. What do you want to do when you say "load and inspect all entity references" when the entity references are undefined? In your example you say you want to show the same result as above (where the result was 5, b but that makes no sense if the undefined entity is &c. Why would you want to display 5, b in this case? Since the entity is undefined ... what would you display? Where are you getting all this bad xml with undefined entities? What do you mean by a typical PHP manual? Why is it splited ? (split?) into 11,000 files?

In the second example, the undefined entity is named b, so it would output the sema result, 5,b, no spaces. I want the entity reference not to be dropped (and so it's name is displayed in code example). About 11k files with (possibly) undefined entities, see PHP manual sources on GitHub.

Hmm, well then your examples are not clear. You said " So far, so good. But if &b; is replaced by, for example, &c;" What would you display for &c.

I guess you are saying you want &c to be turned into simply c (or 5, c)  ... I'm not sure that makes sense. That's just invalid XML because of the undefined entity. The better solution would be to get the entity defined. Since these PHP manuals are real things available on github, can't you give a practical example using a real document? Its hard to believe that such documentation is in this state (i.e., unuseable). Maybe you are just missing a step where you load the entities?
